# How can I delete a RabbitMq exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq

I can easily delete queues, like this:

`rabbitmqadmin delete queue name='MyQ'`

However, I cannot find a way to delete exchanges. What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

➜

```
./rabbitmqadmin  delete exchange  name='myexchange'
exchange deleted
```

Comment: How do you delete an exchange that isn't on the default vhost?

Comment: very old but had the same problem: /rabbitmqadmin -V vhost delete exchange  name='myexchange'

Comment: Is there a way to delete all/multiple exchanges???

Comment: here you can find some useful command line https://github.com/Gsantomaggio/rabbitmq-utils/blob/master/command_line_tools/command_line_tools

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the same functionality with the `rabbitmq management` web interface,
usually accessible via `localhost:15672`

(the rabbitmq management plugin need to be installed, usually the case)

Comment: My web interface throws a 500 error when clicking on exchanges, does this happen to anyone else?